# Delete certain digits from a column in python

Tags: python

I have this column of a DataFrame of integer values on the form '20220401' (watch the picture of the Input), but I want to delete the last two digits of the integer so that all the records of that column be like '202204'. I already tried to convert it to a string and separate it, I tried methods to delete records like [:2] but nothing works  I try to find on the internet but I need HELP PLEASE! [image: Input] [image: Output]

Comment: There is no need for this data to be inserted as images. Also, please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the column be integer already, I don't see why we can't just divide by 100 and take the floor:

```py
df["NEW_DATE"] = df["DATE"].floordiv(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Convert the series to a string](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype), then use [`str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas.Series.str.slice) to keep the first 6 characters.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [20220401, 20220402, 20220803]})

df['d'] = df['d'].astype(str).str.slice(0, 6)

print(df)
```

```
        d
0  202204
1  202204
2  202208
```